# Microsoft Access can't find the field '|1' referred to in your expression

Tags: ms-access

[image]

I'm unable to trace why getting this error in `Dlookup` ... request someone to please assist.

```
Dim val As String
Dim srn As String
srn = Me.Service_Registration_Number.Value
val = DLookup("QTR_Service", "Service_MasterData", ["Service_Registration_Number ='" & srn & "'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You spoiled up the string concatenation for the condition a bit:

```
Dim srn As String
srn = Me.Service_Registration_Number.Value

Dim val As String
val = DLookup("QTR_Service", "Service_MasterData", "[Service_Registration_Number] = '" & srn & "'")
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the assistance ... yes it worked actually i am not expert in Access or any programming language so i have poor skill to understand to define the single quote and double quote ..Thank you lot for the help

Comment: @Amitjha: You're welcome. Please consider [accepting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if you find that it solved your problem.